# Angular UI Router promise resolution and transition

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router, q

I am using ui-router 0.2.0 (I know it is an older version but we are locked on Angular 1.0.8 for various reasons) and trying to use `resolve: {}` to ensure controllers are dealing with concrete data and not eventual data (promises).

I currently have the following:

```
resolve: {
    items: ['listSvc', function (listSvc) {
        console.log('resovling items');
        var items = listSvc.getItems();
        items.then(function () {
            console.log('horray!');
        });
        return items;
    }]
}
```

Items contains about eight items right now just with a title and my view just does a `ng-repeat` and displays each title.

The controller:

```
App.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'items', function ($scope, items) {
    console.log('MyCtrl');
    $scope.items = items;
}]);
```

The view:

```
<div>
    <h1>Items</h1>
     <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{ item.Title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes I am seeing approximately 2 seconds elapse between when I see 'horray!' and the resulting view. Other times I see 'horray!' but never transition to the expected view. How do I troubleshoot/fix this?

My listSvc is also using Q rather than $q if that matters.

Edit: moved question to the bottom for clairity

Edit:

While the selected answer worked for all my jsbin testing and is correct according to all documentation I have found. This is what fixed my actual problem, I know its nasty and awful, but it is the only thing I could get to work for our application. In the example below, my listSvc is using `Q`

```
    resolve: {
        items: ['listSvc', 'currentUser', '$q', '$rootScope', function (listSvc, currentUser, $q, $rootScope) {
            console.log('my => items');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            listSvc.setUser(currentUser);
            listSvc.getMyItems().then(function (myItems) {
                deferred.resolve(myItems);
                return myItems;
            }).fin(function () {
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem/question?

Comment: Sometimes I am seeing approximately 2 seconds elapse between when I see 'horray!' and the resulting view. Other times I see 'horray!' but never transition to the expected view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My listSvc is also using Q rather than $q if that matters.

Yes, yes it does. This is your problem.

Q is a much more complete promise implementation than `$q`, it has a lot more features. However `$q` integrates into the AngularJS digest cycle.

- Informally - it notifies the presentation that something has changed and it needs to refresh.
- Formally - Q resolves promises using the asap.js module for fast queuing (recently), and $q resolves promises on the evalAsync queue. The informal part is more important here though.

My suggestion would be instead of using tricks like a scope apply in a `.finally` uniformally - use `$q.when(prom)` which is a utility method that takes a thenable (generic promise) and turns it into a trusted `$q` promise. If you don't have anything that runs in $q, you'll still need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` at the end of your promise chain.

If that doesn't work, you can simply add

```
.finally(function(){ $scope.apply(); })
```

To the end of your promise chains.

Most good promise libraries implement the A+ specification that allows clean and simply assimilation of one kind of promise into another. Since both Q and $q are Promises/A+ complaint - this means you can interop between Q and $q very easily (since they have similar .then semantics):

> **when(value)** - Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

In your case - something like:

```
var items = $q.when(listSvc.getItems()); // don't forget to inject $q
```

Or wrap it in a `when` at any other point in the chain.

Comment: When using `$q` directly my promises don't seem to be resolving properly, when using `$rootScope.$apply()` with `Q` or `$q.when()` my ui is not updating unless I click in a parent view textbox. This seems to be specific to my app, because if I make a similar jsbin all works fine. Does this behavior indicate something specific I should be looking at?

Comment: @RyanHirsch and `$scope.apply()` in a `.finally` of the Q promise doesn't work?

Comment: Not in my actual application no :( I have updated my original question with what worked in my scenario, however, your answer is correct according to everything I tested outside my application.

Comment: So you explicitly convert the Q promise into a $q promise and `$apply` ? I wonder why `$apply` in `.fin` is not enough. Interesting. If you can create a sample (or end up with one by mistake) let me know I'll take a look :)